# IIS WordPress causing Curl error 18

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Using Web platform installer, I have installed WordPress Version 4.7.2 and PHP5.5.38.

All seems to be working OK until I come to install anything from the admin section. This includes :

- Themes
- plugins

I receive the following error :

```
Installation failed: Download failed. cURL error 18: transfer closed with 17311 bytes remaining to read.
```

I don't really know where to begin to fix this, and can find nothing on google. 
Any advise / help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have console access to the hosting server try accessing the link directly.  My issue was that the hosting server was unable to download files due to a firewall configuration option.